# How to add content above list view using JS?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, office-365, jslink

I am using JSLink code I found at [Office Dev Center](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a) to modify my fields showing percent values to display progress bars. What I would like to do further is add some text above the list itself, dynamically using JS. I am coding in Office 365 platform, so Content Editor Web Part is not available to me.

Is there a way to modify my code so that it includes, e.g., "TEST TEST TEST" string above the list view? Where would I need to edit my script?

```
(function () { 
   var context = {};
   context.Templates = {};

   //I am assuming I should add something like context.Templates.SOMETHING here...

   context.Templates.Fields = {
      "PercentComplete": {
         "View": progressBarViewFieldTemplate
      },
      "Budget": {
         "View": progressBarViewFieldTemplate
      },
      "Hours": {
         "View": progressBarViewFieldTemplate
      }
   };
   SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(context);
})(); 

// PercentComplete, Budget, Hours rendering for Views
function progressBarViewFieldTemplate(context) { 
   var fieldValue = context.CurrentItem[context.CurrentFieldSchema.Name];
   var percent = fieldValue.replace(/\D/g,'');
   return "<div style='background-color: #e5e5e5; width: 50px; display:inline-block;'><div style='width: " + percent + "%; background-color: #369aca;'>&nbsp;</div></div>&nbsp;" + fieldValue;
}
```

Comment: You can [override the entire view](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/04/04/color-code-list-items-with-javascript-using-js-link-in-sharepoint-2013/) instead of just fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a postRender event, then modifying the Pagetitle element.

Add the first line at your comment (//I am assuming .....)

```
context.OnPostRender = postRenderHandler;

function postRenderHandler(ctx) {

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var parent = $("#pageTitle");
        $("<span id='spanId'>TESTING</span>").appendTo(parent);
    });
}
```

Comment: I have tested this on-Prem and it works.

Comment: Works on SharePoint Online as well.

Answer (score 2):

The following script demonstrates how to render an additional caption for List View:

```
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
   OnPostRender: function() { 
        $('table.ms-listviewtable').before('<h1>List of Microsoft Offices</h1>');
   }
});
```

Result

[image]